# Mapping jna with pointer

Tags: java, c, jna

I tried to use a C library with JNA in Java. I use Linux for my project.

I want to map a `.so` native library but I have an error.  I think the problem is from my mapping

The C function is:

```c
void updateTarget(
    int idcar,
    double *carPosition,
    double *carVelocity,
    double isABT,
    double *busPosition,
    double *busVelocity,
    double *pip,
    double *tgo
);
```

This function modifies `busPosition`, `busVelocity`, `pip`, and `*go` values.

I tried this in Java

```java
void updateTarget(
    int idcar,
    double[] carPosition,
    double[] carVelocity,
    double isABT,
    double[] busPosition,
    double[] busVelocity,
    double pip,
    double tgo
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables with `*` are pointers to data elsewhere. You are given the information the data at these pointer locations is one or more `double` values.  So the correct mapping is probably going to either be `DoubleByReference` for a single value, or the `double[]` arrays you have mapped if the native function is actually an array.  But you need to read the native function documentation to determine that.

In your method you missed using either the `ByReference` or array mapping for the last two arguments, `pip` and `tgo`.

Also note that you need to deal with native memory allocations.  In the case that you use `DoubleByReference`, JNA handles allocating the 8 bytes needed.  In the case that you define a primitive `double[]` array, JNA also will allocate the memory for the size of the array when you pass it to the native function, but if the return value requires more space than you have allocated, you'll generate errors.